# Android: Menù popup with long click?

Tags: android, onclick, buttonclick, long-click

I need to implement a menù that appears with a long click around a button, so the user can choose with option he wants to take simply sliding toward a certain direction. Is there any way to do that? I have just a setOnLongClickListener with a onLongClick method for now.

```
btn01.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
            public boolean onLongClick (View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Button 01 long clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

In your Activity :

```
    btn01.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener(){
        public boolean onLongClick (View view) {
            registerForContextMenu(btn01);
            openContextMenu(btn01);
            return true;
        }
    });

    @Override
    public void onCreateContextMenu (ContextMenu menu, View v, ContextMenu.ContextMenuInfo menuInfo){
        //Context menu
        menu.setHeaderTitle("My Context Menu");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW, Menu.NONE, "Add");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT, Menu.NONE, "Edit");
        menu.add(Menu.NONE, CONTEXT_MENU_ARCHIVE, Menu.NONE, "Delete");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onContextItemSelected (MenuItem item){
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case CONTEXT_MENU_VIEW: {

            }
            break;
            case CONTEXT_MENU_EDIT: {
                // Edit Action

            }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, I understand the logic, but not how to adjust my code. I have this listener inside the "onCreate" method contained by "public class ScoutActivity", and when I try to place your suggestion I got errors like "onCreateContextMenu variable is never used" (but it should be a method?!) cannot resolve symbols, ecc..

Comment: I'll paste my code tonight, however I checked better for your  the "ContextMenu" and saw that it is not what I need. I want something similar to a circular menu: if the user long clicks the button, a circle appears and he has to slide to a direction.

Comment: OK. Maybe with this lib it can help: https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android